# WM_POPUP on resize cutting of drawn border

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a window that i'm trying to draw everything in my self, including title bar, borders.

My problem is that when i drag my window from the bottom right to resize it.

My right/bottom border get cut of when i'm making my window smaller, seems to work fine when dragging it bigger.

If i remove CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW it just messes up the borders and it all ends up black from where i drag. ( i seen somewhere that it is better to not use these styles to stop flicker)

I'm not sure if im using the correct styles in my window to be able to do what i want here. My end goal is to draw everything in my window including title bar, borders, buttons and all controls.

```
bool Window::Create(const wchar_t *title, Vector2D size)
{
    HINSTANCE instanceHandle = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    if (this->RegisterWindowClass())
    {
        m_handle = (HWND)CreateWindowEx(0, VERSION, L"", WS_POPUP, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, size.m_x, size.m_y, NULL, NULL, instanceHandle, this);

        if (m_handle)
        {
            ::ShowWindow(m_handle, SW_SHOW);
        }
    }

    return m_handle != 0;
}

bool Window::RegisterWindowClass(const wchar_t *title)
{
    static bool registered = false;
    if (!registered)
    {
        HINSTANCE instanceHandle = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
        WNDCLASSEX windowClass;
        windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        windowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        windowClass.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)Window::WindowProc;
        windowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
        windowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
        windowClass.hInstance = instanceHandle;
        windowClass.hIcon = NULL;
        windowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        windowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(CreateSolidBrush(RGB(60, 60, 60)));//set back color to window
        windowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
        windowClass.lpszClassName = title;
        windowClass.hIconSm = NULL;

        if (RegisterClassEx(&windowClass))
            registered = true;
    }

    return registered;
}

void Draw_LeftRightBottom_Rectangles(HDC hdc, HBRUSH brush, RECT rect, int TaskbarHeight)
{
    RECT leftrect, rightrect, bottomrect;
    leftrect.left = 0;
    leftrect.top = TaskbarHeight;
    leftrect.right = 2;
    leftrect.bottom = rect.bottom;
    //fill left rect of window for border
    FillRect(hdc, &leftrect, brush);

    rightrect.left = rect.right - 2;
    rightrect.top = TaskbarHeight;
    rightrect.right = rect.right;
    rightrect.bottom = rect.bottom;
    //fill right rect of window
    FillRect(hdc, &rightrect, brush);

    bottomrect.left = 0;
    bottomrect.top = rect.bottom - 2;
    bottomrect.right = rect.right;
    bottomrect.bottom = rect.bottom;
    //fill bottom rect of window
    FillRect(hdc, &bottomrect, brush);
}

LRESULT Window::WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static int X, Y;
    Window* pThis;
    if (uMsg == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
        pThis = static_cast<Window*>(reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT*>(lParam)->lpCreateParams);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(pThis));
    }
    else
        pThis = reinterpret_cast<Window*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA));


    if (pThis != 0)
    {
        switch (uMsg)
        {
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            RECT clientArea;
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &clientArea);

            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            if (BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps))
            {
                //Creating double buffer
                HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(ps.hdc);
                int ndcmem = SaveDC(hdcMem);
                HBITMAP hbmMem = CreateCompatibleBitmap(ps.hdc, X, Y);
                SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmMem);
                //-------------------------------------------------------

                // Copy background bitmap into double buffer
                BitBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, clientArea.right, clientArea.bottom, ps.hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
                //---------------------------------------------------------

                RECT rect;
                rect.bottom = 25;
                rect.right = clientArea.right;
                HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
                // Draw Titlebar
                FillRect(hdcMem, &rect, brush);

                Draw_LeftRightBottom_Rectangles(hdcMem, brush, clientArea, 25);

                DeleteObject(brush);

                //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

                // Copy double buffer to screen
                BitBlt(ps.hdc, 0, 0, X, Y, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
                //--------------------------------------------------

                // Clean up
                RestoreDC(hdcMem, ndcmem);
                DeleteObject(hbmMem);
                DeleteDC(hdcMem);
                EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
                //--------------------
            }
                return 0;;
        }

        case WM_SIZE:
        {
            X = LOWORD(lParam);
            Y = HIWORD(lParam);
            break;
        }

        case WM_NCHITTEST:
        {
            POINT pt;
            RECT rc;
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);

            pt.x = LOWORD(lParam);
            pt.y = HIWORD(lParam);
            ScreenToClient(hwnd, &pt);

            if (pt.y > (rc.bottom - BORDERWIDTH))
            {
                if (pt.x>(rc.right - BORDERWIDTH))
                {
                    return HTBOTTOMRIGHT;
                }
            }

            if (pt.y < 25)
            {
                return HTCAPTION;
            }

            break;
        }
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Why do you use static variables `X` and `Y` (which should be called `width` and `height`) when you call `GetClientRect()` anyway in WM_PAINT. Then you inconsistently use `X` and `Y` for some calls and `clientArea` for other.

Comment: @zett42 Forgot to delete them and change it.

Comment: WM_PAINT is only for drawing the client area of the window.  For the title bar, etc, you need to handle WM_NCPAINT

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson so i can use `WM_NCPAINT` to draw anywhere on my window? should i be using both or can i get away with just using `WM_NCPAINT`?

Comment: Should be using both.  One is for the non-client area (WM_NCPAINT), one is for the client area (WM_PAINT).